# Resize the MPMoviePlayerController dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

How can I resize the MPMoviePlayerController dynamically to fix all the size of screens for iPhone/iPad (both portrait & landscape)?

this is my code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *about = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"About" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(openPopup)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = about;


NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/streamUrl/playlist.m3u8"];

_streamPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:streamURL];


self.streamPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

[self.view addSubview: self.streamPlayer.view];

[self.streamPlayer play];


}
```

I also tried to add

```
[self.streamPlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

but this makes the video is not fix to screen as shown in screenshot

[image]

How can I make it fix all screens of all different devices?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: self.view=self.streamPlayer;

Comment: tried this and this causes an Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I found is to use the following

```
 CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
 CGFloat height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

 [self.streamPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10 ,height-20, width-70)];
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem in ios 5
as:

```
AvPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer =[[AVPlayerLayer alloc]init];
avPlayerLayer = [[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer] retain];
avPlayerLayer.frame = self.playerView.layer.bounds;
avPlayerLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0, 0, 0, 1);

[self.playerView.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
```

here is avPlayerLayer.transform you can set it in any direction .

Comment: you just need to add AVPlayerLayer and add into the AVPlayer then you can change any Tranform of the player ..

Comment: please ensure that this code is right or not because xcode tells me that there are errors in this code

Comment: ya i am using in my app this code for orientation What errors you get ?

Comment: AvPlayerLayer, where is the definition of the avPlayer and playerView?

Comment: Please check also your nib file and also if you create in portrait mode then change it into landscape mode then set frame again then you can get exact result !!

Comment: ok First Check your viewcontroller , in nib file you create with portrait mode change it into landscape mode.. and tell me then ios version you are using ?

Comment: I made my project landscape by default and I'm not using nib, I'm using xib

Comment: the view which you are used for avplayer check that view !

Comment: it is the main view of the application (MFViewController)

Answer (score 0):

```
 MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:contentURL]];
        if (moviePlayerViewController) {


            [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];
            [moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

            if ([moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsAirPlay:)]) {
                [moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer setAllowsAirPlay:YES];
            }

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerViewController queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
                [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
            }];
            [moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];
        }
```

Comment: when I try to use this it leads to open the videoPlayer for 2 seconds the disappear and open my viewController

Comment: remove   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerViewController queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
                [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
            }];

Comment: i Think you use     [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:YES]; method which is not for xcode 4.5
?

Comment: No, I'm not using this line.

Comment: it is difficult to debug you need to provide code :- maheepkaushal@gmail.com